How do I write a query to compare ticket volume for weekdays vs weekend
I want to compare the ticket volumes created on a every weekends vs the volume of ticket on every weekdays. I am using a 2023 dataset from January to December.
SELECT 
    DATENAME(DW, Created_time) AS Daily_Volume, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Ticket_ID) AS Total_Request 
FROM 
    [SLA DB].[dbo].[data_challenge]
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(DW, Created_time)

I used these queries and it returned the cumulative volumes for every week of the year. I am not sure i have done the right thing. I think in comparison I should have a column for weekday that shows all volumes and a column for weekend that shows all volumes for weekend.
How do I create separate columns that captures all data for weekday and weekend from my dataset?
SELECT 
    DATENAME(DW, Created_time) AS Daily_Volume, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Ticket_ID) AS Total_Request 
FROM 
    [SLA DB].[dbo].[data_challenge]  
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(DW, Created_time)




Ticket_ID
Priority
Source
Created_time




1012
Low
Email
2023-01-02 00:58:00.0000000


1013
High
Phone
2023-01-02 07:27:00.0000000


1014
Low
Chat
2023-01-02 06:59:00.0000000


1015
Medium
Email
2023-01-03 03:09:00.0000000


1016
Low
Email
2023-01-03 00:03:00.0000000




Can you share the schema of the table and some sample data? Just 5 rows would be enough. Also I think you should add the sql-server tag to your question, since DATENAME is a SQL-Server specific function.

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/SX3vrtnL for an example to get you started.

As a side note, I really recommend using the actual name of the period you want, not abbreviations. It's easier for everyone to understand what part you are after then.

thanks for your response. i  have added the schemas. i am using ssms

You need to define when your week starts. I figure the week probably starts on Monday and the weekend following the end of that work week is what a typical business would want in the side-by-side. Of course if this is just a learning exercise then it can be whatever you want.

Presumably your week is set to start on Monday as you are in Austria. (Run select @@datefirst looking for a result of 1 to confirm.) You will also generally have partial weeks at the beginning and end of the year if the data runs for the entirety of January through December. Once you get the week definition set then the last grouping column (after logical week) can just be case when datepart(weekday, Created_time) between 1 and 5 then 'Weekday' else 'Weekend' end

Thanks very much @everyone. these contributions helped me to solve the problems..
